# How to prototype with real text input?

Tags: prototype

I need to test a series of forms, and the classic invision click-and-fill-in method is really biasing my testing results. The user really needs to experience the act of typing in information, to get a real feel for how the product would work. What prototyping tools allow for text input interactions?
Bonus points if compatible with figma.

Comment: Protopie is a good option

Answer (score 1):

For quick user feedback I use codepen and mock-up my designs into a useable demo, this way I can send someone a link and get feedback from real interactions. Of course the code doesn’t have to be production quality, it just needs to convey how I see something working and it’s a great starting point to refining functionality etc

Answer (score 0):

I use plain HTML/CSS to create a basic prototype for such pattern behavioural tests. It should not take much time if it just a form.

Otherwise Axure can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well that means you'd have to go for a more complex prototyping tool like **[Axure](https://www.axure.com/)**.

You could basically just import your screen images there and place a [text field](https://docs.axure.com/axure-rp/widgets/text-fields-text-areas/) on top (works on mobile too).

[image: Axure screenshot]

The only drawback is that you can't mass-import your images like you can in Invision, so it costs extra effort to create the screens. But if you don't have many screens and instead more focus on interaction, Axure is definitely the tool to go.

---

**Edit:** Felt like I should add that you have the possibility to create complex interactions with this too, like checking the content after a button click or even after each letter with `onTextChanged`:

[image]